# Chrome and Firefox on Android render Etruscan letters incorrectly (flipped, but written left-to-right)

Tags: android, unicode

I have written an Etruscan sentence on [my blog-post about names of places](https://flatassembler.github.io/toponyms.html).

On my Linux desktop, they are rendered as intended, both in Firefox and in Chrome:

[image: How the Etruscan letters are rendered on desktop]

So, the letters are written left-to-right and the letters are oriented the same as corresponding capital Latin or Greek letters (as is usual for Etruscan).

However, on Android, in both Firefox and Chrome, they are rendered like this:

[image: How the Etruscan letters are rendered on Android]

That is incorrect rendering. The letters are written as if the Etruscan sentence was written right-to-left (the 'E' and 'L' are flipped, for example), but the sentence is actually written left-to-right.

So, what would you recommend me to do about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received some answer here: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/m63x4p/chrome_and_firefox_on_android_render_etruscan/gr3t6h2/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

In short, it is about the default Sans-Serif fonts on Android and Linux... including different forms for Etruscan letters.